# How to create a Postgres event trigger to assign standard roles on objects

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'd like to ensure all schemas/objects in my Postgres (AWS/RDS) instance get a standard role based on object naming conventions, and automatically apply the standard role after an object is created or updated.

I've started with a function created on the `public` schema, and a trigger that should invoke the function for any DDL change.  The logic of the function should grant permissions to the schema/object when it is created or updated if the name starts with `rt_`.

**Example Function:**

```
DECLARE
    obj record;
BEGIN
FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '% event object: %.% %',
                 tg_tag,
                 obj.object_type,
                 obj.schema_name,
                 obj.object_identity;
    INSERT INTO public.pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands_log(
        object_type, 
        shema_name, 
        object_identity, 
        tg_tag
    )
    VALUES (obj.object_type, obj.schema_name, obj.object_identity, tg_tag);

    IF obj.object_identity ~ '^rt_' THEN

        -- EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %I TO MY_ROLE;', obj.schema_name);

    END IF; 

END LOOP;
END;
```

To test the above, I see the conditional `IF obj.object_identity ~ '^rt_' THEN` works as expected, but the `EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %I TO MY_ROLE;', obj.schema_name);` fails with the following error:

> ERROR: role "my_role" does not exist
>
> CONTEXT: SQL statement "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA rt_some_schema TO MY_ROLE;"
>
> PL/pgSQL function et_assign_schema_role_permissions() line 21 at EXECUTE

The role definitely exists in the database.  How can I automatically assign a role?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the error more closely, I saw the value "my_role" was lower case.  Looks like this was an issue where Postgres requires quotes around the object to ensure casing is proper.

```
EXECUTE format('GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA %I TO "MY_ROLE";', obj.schema_name);
```